# Is it okay that random_shuffle uses rand()?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to use the `random_shuffle()` function from `<algorithm>`, but when I looked at it, it turns out it uses `rand()` under the covers. Is this ok for the purposes of shuffling? I was under the impression that `rand()` is not a very good source of random values and it's best to use something like the Mersenne Twister from `<random>`.

Comment: In C++14, `random_shuffle` is deprecated for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred method is to use `std::shuffle`:

```
std::shuffle(begin(), end(), std::mt19937());
```

`std::random_shuffle()`'s source of randomness is undefined. The Visual C++ team has commented on this, saying they're going to keep it using `rand()` rather than something better so that it will remain backward-compatible.